# Linux Mint 19.1 lagging/freezing when run off pen drive

Tags: linux, linux-mint, liveusb

I've "installed" LM 19.1 to a PNY 16Gb (2.0) pendrive. From the outset, it has lagged (severely) and sometimes freezes.

Example: from "splashscreen" to fully operable "homepage" takes 8-10 mins.

Once home page establishes, going to "browser" takes up towards 5-7 mins to "fully" establish.

When D/ling, it often freezes and , at best, I saw D/l speeds of 400-500 kbs. To D/l and fully install VLC took nearly an hour.

The way LM 19.1 operates is unacceptable and I've been seeking (via other forums & "net") info that would alleviate these symptoms.

I've always liked LM, but the last 2 versions(18 series and now 19 series) have posed quite a few unnecessary problems.

Used to run 17.3 and worked like a champ (from USB stick). I'd appreciate some good advice/help.

Comment: If you open up a resource monitor, can you find out what your disk and cpu usage is like? It sounds like there's a lot of disk io problems.

Comment: When you ran mint in the past, was it off the same pendrive?

Comment: Could you install it to a different pendrive and verify the symptoms persist? I may be your drive has become damaged, affecting its speed.

Comment: What is the "home page"  of an operating system?

Comment: RE:  BlueDrink9     Appreciate your responding. I've been told that running a 'full install" from a pendrive isn't the best way to go about it. Running "live" is supposed to be much more efficient and easier on the pendrive. Ok, looks like I'll try that and hope things operate much better. Oh, and no, I've tested this pendrive via many different tests (usually first thing I do) and every test indicated the drive was "healthy".  P.S. anyone tell me how to mark thread "solved"?

Comment: I think I've asked this before, but am still in the dark "Where does one "log-out"?

Comment: Both Mint 18 and 19 have been giving me problems that 17 didn't have. They're just too unstable and unpredictable to use for either home or business. I've installed them on friends machines only to find they constantly crash and burn, unlike Mint 17 which was stable as. I'm now actively looking for an alternative distro, so far evaulated Manjaro, MX Linux, Ububntu, Fedora. Given I don't like rolling releases (Arch based) and duplicated repos (Manjaro), I'm going back to basics and testing Debian. It's such a fine distro, all the bells and whistles provided by Mint can be foregone for some stab

Comment: RE: johnny2   Well, your one of the first persons I've had agree with me. As it is, I'm still trying to get 19.1x to "install and run correctly" from a pendrive. This has been an endeavor that, even with all the help I've received, has been a failure w/ no correct procedure/repair. Many have offered advice and I've tried many, but ultimately, the O.S. always fails at some point. I used to run LM 17.3X from a pendrive with no trouble. LM 18 & 19 have been a source of constant aggravation/failure.

Comment: RE: BlueDrink9;  Reply to query Feb.9@21:22   I've installed to an 8Gb-2.0, 16Gb-2.0, 16Gb-3.0 and, 32Gb-3.0; tried LM 19.1 'cinnamon" all w/ like results. I've been reading/re-reading post concerning set-up that blocks/disables main HDD/O.S. prior to boot. Just for "reference", I "installed" puppylinux to see if it would work. Ran like a champ! And, noticed it did not change the Fat32 format to .ext4. So, it seems, that must be the answer(???) Well, so, also been reading/re-reading about Manjaro. No decisions yet, just know I can't deal w/ LM as it is now.  THANX